How can I structure a Javascript object to record colour themes for seven items
I have an LED clock with the following elements that can take an RGB value

C for Cardinal points (ie 3,6,9,12 hrs or 15,30,45,60 mins)
F for One hour/Five minute points (ie 1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11 hrs or 5,10,20,25,35,40,50,55 mins)
H for Hour hand
M for Minute hand
CF for all points at night (Hour points AND Cardinal points, combined)
Hn for Hour hand at night
Mn for Minute hand at night

I want to create a few themes, so I want to create a JavaScript theme object that stores the seven RGB values and then populate named instances of it with RGB values. I'm doing this in NodeRed and the idea is that a user can pick one of the themes from a list in the NodeRed dashboard, which will publish 7 MQTT topics each containing a payload of the relevant part of the theme object. An ESP32 subscribes to those topics and colours the correct LEDs according to the payload RGB value. I am struggling to decide how to efficiently construct the theme object. So far, I've got:
let theme = {
  themeName: "",
  C:[R,G,B],
  F:[R,G,B],
  H:[R,G,B],
  M:[R,G,B],
  CF:[R,G,B],
  Hn:[R,G,B],
  Mn:[R,G,B]
}

Is this along the right lines and do I populate the R, G & B values with a default set or is there a way to specify the object without values. Also, do I need to declare the R,G & B type int

"type int" - if you want typed variable, use typescript. Not sure if that's an option for node-red

Thanks @bravo but tbh the type declaration was more of an afterthought. Main need is - is my object declation structured right?

I wouldn't know as I'm not familiar with whatever it is that theme object is supposed to work with

@bravo - see my description in my post, though it's sort of irrelevant (hint:JavaScript objects - A theme is fairly self explanatory - I want to store several sets of seven colours in discrete R,G,B values)

Oh, so it's not supposed to follow any particular format, just a format of your own design - then if it's valid syntax, I guess it "works"

OK Yes! Is what I've suggested a valid JS Obj? I'm after some solid help here

yes, it is syntactically correct, the only thing is, are R G and B declared variables? Their values will only be used to initialise the object, changing them wont change anything once the object has been created (assuming they are primitives of course)

Is it an effective structure to do what I need or are there other alternatives. If so, what are there relative merits?

I need to be able to instantiate a theme and then parameterise C, F, H, M, etc in each instance with values for R, G & B

where do the values for R G and B come from. The format you are using, C, F, H, M etc will all have same values for R, G and B
